# Putting my own cls files into Texlive 2020

Tags: path, lyx, cls, tex-live

I am writing a book for which the publisher (Springer) has sent me a .cls file (svmono.cls). I am using LyX on Windows 10, and have just installed texlive (complete 6 Gb default installation), as it is LyX's preferred TeX distribution. Unfortunately, I can't determine where to store svmono.cls, and how to make LyX and Texlive pick it up.

The relevant paths are as follows:

Texlive Installation folder: `c:\texlive`,

This folder, in turn, has two subfolders:  `c:\texlive\2020` and `c:\texlive\texmf-local`.

I assumed that I would have to put my cls files in `texmf-local`, in particular under `c:\texlive\texmf_local\tex\latex\local\`, and so copied svmono.cls to this directory, but when I open my document in  LyX, I get a warning message (LyX Document class is not available .... document cannot be compiled until the following prerequisites are installed..... svmono.cls).

I have tried looking into the LyX manual, which refers me to the Customization guide, which I can't print, so I'm really at a loss here, and would greatly appreciate guidance with two issues:

1. In which folder should I place svmono.cls (in particular, should I create a `Springer` folder under some parent folder to hold the Springer cls file)
2. Once I place the file in the right directory, what next do I need to do in order to ensure that Texlive and Lyx import it correctly.

Sincerely and with many thanks in advance

Thomas Philips

Comment: For tlmgr, I'm not too knowledgeable. What I run (on Ubuntu) is `mktexlsr`. For LyX, after you figure out the correct tlmgr command, run Tools > Reconfigure and restart LyX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment by scottkosky + comparisons to a working Miktex installation pointed me in the right direction. Here are the things I needed to do to make Lyx 2.3.6 work with Tex Live 2020.

1. Do the default (6 GB) install of Tex Live. Open the Tex Live Shell from the Windows Apps menu,  click on Mark All to select all installed packages and then click on Update all. While the 6 GB install is large, it gave me all the packages I could ever possibly need.
2. Copy my Springer cls files to `c:\texlive\texmf_local\tex\latex\` (NOT `c:\texlive\texmf_local\tex\latex\local\`) and from Tex Live's menu bar, select Actions > Regenerate Filenames Database
3. In Lyx, Click on Tools, Preferences > Paths and then update Path and click on OK. My path was missing the location of my R interpreter and Acrobat Reader. The following path works well for me; `C:\texlive\2020\bin\win32;$LyXDir\bin;$LyXDir\Python;$LyXDir\Python\Lib;$LyXDir\Perl\bin;$LyXDir\imagemagick;$LyXDir\ghostscript\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader;C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.3\bin`. Keep in mind that your paths may be different.
4. Finally, click on Tools > Reconfigure in LyX, then close and restart LyX.

It works perfectly now.

Thomas Philips